# What are 'keywords' in BibTex files good for?

Tags: bibtex

I've recently seen that my .bib file (which I manage via [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/)) makes use of the attribute 'Keywords' for each entry. This seems not to be used in the document after rendering. So what is the attribute 'Keywords' good for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mostly, it is used to allow for searching or sorting based on, surprisingly, key words. That way, if an article deals with a concept which is not part of the title, abstract, etc, you can add the key word and then it will appear in searches in your reference manager. In your case JabRef.

Frequently, the field is populated already in on-line databases.

You can also use it with biblatex to create bibliographies of words with only specific key words, for example `\printbibliography[keyword=BurnoutAppendixBib, title={Burnout Appendix}]` will create a bibliography containing items only with the keyword BurnoutAppendixBib.